# Will the frequency 122.000 MHz no longer be used for Flight Watch after October 1st 2015?

Tags: faa-regulations, radio-communications

The [Flight Service Program Changes](http://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/ato/service_units/systemops/fs/changes/) announcement from the FAA includes

> On October 1, 2015, the FAA will consolidate Flight Watch services into routine flight services inflight frequencies to eliminate unnecessary duplication of service and provide greater convenience for pilots. These services provide inflight weather information to pilots. After that date, these services will be available on the same frequencies that pilots use to open and close flight plans and to receive updates on NOTAMs or Temporary Flight Restrictions (TFRs). Dedicated Flight Watch frequencies will be decommissioned.

What are the “dedicated Flight Watch frequencies,” plural? The mnemonic drilled into my head was Flight Watch on 122.0, with the zero shaped like the face of a wrist watch.

The only frequencies I, a student pilot, have ever used for opening and closing flight plans has been [RCO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_communications_outlet). The wording above is not specific, so does that mean instead of one dedicated frequency, you have to know the local RCO frequency to call Flight Watch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below 18,000 feet MSL, En Route Flight Advisory Service (EFAS) (a.k.a. Flight Watch) is provided on 122.0 MHz. Above this altitude, it is provided on discrete frequencies, with each one serving a specific ARTCC area ([see AIM 7-1-5](http://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/aim/aim0701.html#IGH3a2JACK), [FAA JO 7210.3Y Section 3](http://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/fac/1403.html)).  These discrete frequencies are listed in the margin of IFR Enroute High Altitude charts:

[image]

To answer your original question, the FAA plans to consolidate EFAS onto existing Flight Service Station (FSS) frequencies on October 1, 2015. Because Lockheed Martin (the FSS contractor) has consolidated flight service stations, the EFAS weather briefers are now co-located with Flight Service personnel (they physically sit next to each other in the same room), making it possible to obtain both services on the same frequency.

At the same time, the FAA will phase out legacy Remote Airport Advisory Services and more significantly, require the ICAO format for all flight plans (international AND DOMESTIC), see [Flight Service Program change announcement](http://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/ato/service_units/systemops/fs/changes/).